# How to sort response data according to alphabets

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am getting response from server like:

```
Name:cat
  id:1

Name:apple
  id:2

Name:rat
  id:3

Name:bat
  id:4
```

How to sort the above response data based on alphabets wise, based on "`Name`".

My requirement is like this:

```
Name:apple
  id:2

Name:bat
  id:4

Name:cat
  id:1

Name:rat
  id:3
```

Can any one suggest me how to implement this?

Comment: So what class instance is the data held in?

Comment: Initially i am getting data from server and storing into model class

Comment: Well you should show the class declaration so that your question can be answered accurately.

Comment: Uh, maybe use a sort algorithm?  If you look at the specs for NSArray and NSMutableArray there are several.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use this Code snippet

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(YourObject*)otherObject {
        return [self.name compare:otherObject.name];
    }

    NSArray *sortedArray;
    sortedArray = [yourNSMArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name"
                                              ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [YourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: Where i sort the data @Maihwak, I mean before insert data to model object (or) after insertion od model object, can you give more clarity..

Comment: @NagarajuKamatham: read the code ... U need to show some effort!

Comment: user sortedArray to supply data in your model object.